# How to remove the Bluetooth icon from the topbar?

Tags: settings, wingpanel, desktop, bluetooth

first Elementary OS user here!

I don't use Bluetooth, so how can I remove it from the top bar. I know that I can disable it, but I want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove bluetooth indicator (in terminal):

```
apt remove wingpanel-indicator-bluetooth switchboard-plug-bluetooth
```

If you never use bluetooth, you can remove bluetooth related packages completely:

```
apt remove bluetooth
```